# Can I read a remote file using APIs in MPI?

Tags: c, mpi

Each machine among N machines has an exclusive portion of data as a binary file. (The files are simply arrays of fixed-size data type)

Can an i-th proc read a specific portion of the data file in j-th proc?;
(for example, i-th proc read 4096 bytes from the beginning of the file in j-th proc.)

It seems `MPI_File_*` operations require to duplicate all the data file into every machine's local file system to have this feature, unless I have distributed parallel file systems.

Comment: What language and operating system are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to sort of emulate this by mean of one-sided MPI communications. From here, I will make a few assumptions (some of which you already confirmed in your question):

1. Your files are binary files, located on a non-shared file system (in my example, each process or rank `r` will access a file named "/tmp/input`r`")
2. Your are on a Linux / Unix cluster (I will use some POSIX functions here which I doubt would work on a Windows machine)
3. Your files are too big to be just read by each process into a buffer and subsequently exposed (although if the files are small, this would probably be the simplest solution)

So the idea is that each process opens its own private file in read mode, memory maps it, and then exposes the memory address returned by `mmap()` into a MPI memory window. Once done, each process can just use this window to access the part of the various files it wants.

Here is what it would look like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );

    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size );

    // Open the local file
    char fname[256];
    snprintf( fname, 256, "/tmp/input%d", rank );
    int fd = open( fname, O_RDONLY );
    // And memory-map it
    struct stat st;
    fstat( fd, &st );
    size_t len = st.st_size;
    void *faddr = mmap( NULL, len, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0 );

    // Create a MPI memory window with the mapped files
    MPI_Win win;
    MPI_Win_create( faddr, len, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win );

    // Each process reads two integers from the next process' private file
    int next = ( rank + 1 ) % size;
    int values[2];

    MPI_Win_lock( MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, next, 0, win );
    MPI_Get( values, 2, MPI_INT, next, 0, 2, MPI_INT, win );
    MPI_Win_unlock( next, win );

    printf( "Process %d read values %d and %d from process %d's private file\n",
            rank, values[0], values[1], next );

    // Cleaning up
    MPI_Win_free( &win );
    munmap( faddr, len );
    close( fd );

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

For the sake of testing, I created some files containing two integers: the rank of the current process and the it added with 10000. I used this on a Linux cluster (with several nodes) and the result was:

```c
~> mpicc -std=c99 mpimap.c -o mpimap
~> mpirun -n 10 ./mpimap 
Process 0 read values 1 and 10001 from process 1's private file
Process 1 read values 2 and 10002 from process 2's private file
Process 2 read values 3 and 10003 from process 3's private file
Process 3 read values 4 and 10004 from process 4's private file
Process 5 read values 6 and 10006 from process 6's private file
Process 6 read values 7 and 10007 from process 7's private file
Process 9 read values 0 and 10000 from process 0's private file
Process 4 read values 5 and 10005 from process 5's private file
Process 7 read values 8 and 10008 from process 8's private file
Process 8 read values 9 and 10009 from process 9's private file
```

As you can see, it works and neither does it require to read the private file in advance, nor does it require to have the files on a shared file system.

Comment: thanks for your interesting solution! Now I have a question. I am using Infiniband's RDMA capability which might bypass OS and even CPU accessing directly to physical memory. I once used MPI APIs over mmap region and found some terrible errors (kernel panic, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263684/c-app-with-mmap-kills-kernel-kernel-panic-with-mmap). Do know any issues related with it?

Comment: I have no prior experience of using this technique, so I cannot say whether or not it triggers bugs on some kernels / kernel modules. What I can tell is that you can try (an enhanced version of) this small code on your cluster and see if you can reproduce your kernel panic. If so, then you have a mcve for your U&L question...

Comment: This probably won't work as expected on RDMA networks, e.g. IB. The driver usually registers the entire buffer region, which means it first prefaults all pages in it and then locks them in physical memory. Therefore, the entire file will be read in, which both defeats the purpose of using `mmap()` and will result in a segfault if the file is bigger than the physical memory.

Comment: @HristoIliev thanks for your helpful reply. it seems like that 'ibv_reg_mr' do the job pinning the entire buffer region. I might be better to use a sort of distributed file system for my purpose.